# How to create new column grouped from another column (like age group from ages)

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I need help in solving this problem, I have checked around but have not seen any answer yet. 
I have a column of various ages, then I want to create a new column based on the frequency of the various ages in the age column.

So given the table below

> age 11 occurs 4 times
> age 21 occurs 3 times
> age 8  occurs 2 times
> age 15 and 43 occurs just once

I am trying to make the new column 'freq' to contain the frequency for each age.

### FROM THIS

[image]

### FINAL OUTPUT

[image]

this code is to generate the sample data above

```
train1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['age','gender'])
train1.loc[0] = np.array([11, 'male'])
train1.loc[1] = np.array([21,'male' ])
train1.loc[2] = np.array([15,'female'])
train1.loc[3] = np.array([11,'female' ])
train1.loc[4] = np.array([21,'male'])
train1.loc[5] = np.array([8,'female'])
train1.loc[6] = np.array([11,'female'])
train1.loc[7] = np.array([43,'male'])
train1.loc[8] = np.array([21,'male'])
train1.loc[9] = np.array([8,'female'])
train1.loc[10] = np.array([11,'female'])
train1['age'] = train1['age'].astype(int)
train1
```

I would really appreciate any help I can get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`train1['freq'] = train1.age.map(train1.age.value_counts())`